# Adding firebase to react.js web application

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hi I just want to be sure that adding firebase script and initializing it in the head tag in the `index.html` is enough in React?

Like I said I have put below code in scrpit tag

```
firebase.initializeApp(somefirebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();
```

Comment: I guess, but it's always preferred ( like a pattern ) to initialize it in the src

Comment: Have a look at react-redux-firebase. It makes it very easy to use firebase with react

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial), the author mentioned that to add the config also there. you can initialize the firebase in the head tag like the below image

[image]